# The principle of PHP inference variable output

Tags: php, output

```
<?php
$b="c";
$c=7;
$i=&$c+$$b;
var_dump($i);
?>
```

Why my output is int(7)?Can you tell me the reason?I think $i value is 7+7=14 but the result let me fuzzy.

Comment: Is there a reason you put the `&` before the `$c`? `$i=$c+$$b;` would give you 14. Maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774130/php-what-does-a-in-front-of-a-variable-name-mean.

Comment: OK thx , let me see.

Comment: but even that , the value of $i should be $c+$$b .actually the output is 7 not 14

Comment: https://eval.in/709799, works for me, also all other versions seem to have the same result, https://3v4l.org/v0bs0

Comment: @chris85 you forgot the & in that test, if you copy his code exactly it doesn't work there either

Comment: @SjorsOttjes No i didn't I told the OP to remove that. See comment 1 and/or comment 3.

Comment: @chris85 my bad. It works in php7 too when you remove the &

Comment: try var dumping this: &$c it will trow an error. That's why it isn't being added to the result

Comment: add & it output value is int(7) yet not 14

Comment: @LukasMeine  ues echo to instead of vardump its value is also 7

Answer (score 0):

It is because of reference. Precedence **Reference + string = Reference**. Consider this.

```
$b = 7;
$a = &$b; // $a now points to $b;
$a = '?'; // The value where $a points is '?'
echo $b;  // 7
```

Now $a is pointer, a reference to $b; You can not add string on that.

The precedence of **&** is being preferred over **+**.
[Check this for more detail](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

**EDIT**
One interesting test for better understanding.

```
$a = 7;
$d = ($c = &$a + 1); // It is composite expression;
echo $c; // again 7 because & is given preference to + 
echo $d; // 8 because that is the output of internal expression.
```

To be very frank, this is weirdly new to me.

Comment: but I output &$c its value is 7 $$b value is 7 so I think $i value will be 14.I can't understand your answer could you make it clearly??

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$i=&$c+$$b;
```

with

```
echo &$c+$$b;
```

and you get a syntax error. Doing

```
$d=3;
$i=&$c+$d;
```

you get also `7`, but doing `$i = $d+&$c;` yields a syntax error. In your example, doing, then, `$i++;` increments both `$i` and `$c`.

The PHP parser expects `VAR = REFERENCE;` and stops after it gets the reference (i.e. it ignores `$$b`). Anyway doing `REF + integer` has a meaning in C derived languages, but not in PHP.

Note that `&` is not only the 'reference' operator, it's also the bitwise (AND) operator. The unary version is for references, the binary one is for bitwise. The language grammar is more complex for `&`, that could explain the problem.

That's a PHP bug. The parser should also yield an error in the example you give. Don't use that anyway as it has no meaning and will be likely / hopefully rejected in future releases.