# Values of array changing without modification, using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have a sample code. Its strange! Even not making any changes in defined array but still my defined array's value got changed.

```
$myarr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($myarr as &$myvalue) {
    $myvalue = $myvalue * 2;
}
print_r($myarr); // Output - Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 6 [3] => 8 )
```

Can you please explain, How it happen?

Comment: remove & in &$myvalue

Comment: Read about [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). Using them in a loop produces unexpected results. This is explained in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: What do you mean? You are multiplying each value in your array by 2, in the foreach statement: $myvalue = $myvalue * 2; The output is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do change the original array because you are using `&` in your array loop.

This signal for [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) as @axiac comments.

In order to avoid changes on your original array use the following for loop:

```
foreach ($myarr as $myvalue)
```

Comment: Thanks David, I could understand that what exactly mean of reference.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing address of myarr, where myvalue uses same address of myarr that why its changing

use this

```
  $myarr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
    foreach ($myarr as $myvalue) {
        $myvalue = $myvalue * 2;
    }
    print_r($myarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it without the "&" before $myvalue?

Please read here [PHP: What does a & in front of a variable name mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774130/php-what-does-a-in-front-of-a-variable-name-mean)