# how different between & new class and new class in php

Tags: php

hello i need ask from different between

```
$var=new class;

$var= & new class;
```

and if different in stack and speed code

thank you

Comment: The first one is correct. The second is deprecated and should not be used. See [PHP new operator returning reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350920/php-new-operator-returning-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are only different if you are using PHP 4 or lower.  Since PHP 5.0, `new` implicitly returns a reference, so there's no need to do `=& new`...  If you're using PHP >= 5.0.0, then there's no reason to use `&` with new.

In fact, as of 5.3, it'll raise an `E_DEPRECATED` error since [it's deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php)...